# How to dynamically Set Query Selector attributes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-selectors, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a Partial view with Markdown Editor i reference this Partial View in Main view along with the id attribute.

```
 @Html.Partial("_MarkdownEditor", new { id = "executivesummary" }) 
 @Html.Partial("_MarkdownEditor", new { id = "editorsection" })
```

Here trying to set id attribute dynamically like this..

```
<div id="@ViewData.Eval("id")">
</div>
```

This all works fine, My problem is i need to capture and set id dynamically to display the editor... here is the editor code. Here i have hard coded the querySelector with #exectuivesummary. I want to set it dynamically based on the id parameter passed to Partial view, so that i can i have different instances of the editor! How can this be done ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var editor = new tui.Editor({
    el: document.querySelector('#executivesummary'),
    previewStyle: 'vertical',   
    height: '300px',
    initialEditType: 'wysiwyg'
    //hideModeSwitch:true
});

function saveContent(e) {
    var content = editor.getValue();
    console.log(content)
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: How about `el: document.querySelector('#@ViewData.Eval("id")')`?

Comment: @ADyson Your Great! I just wanted another pair of Eyes !  Thank you mate !

Answer (score 2):

You must want to use a variable in the querySelector.

You can do it like this:

```js
var id = 'executivesummary';
var matched = document.querySelector('#' + id);
console.log(matched);
```

```html
<div id="executivesummary"></div>
```

In your case, you may do this: `el: document.querySelector('#' + @ViewData.Eval("id"));`

Hope it helps.